# How to implement a validation on image size and compress its size when exceeding the size limit in spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, configuration, interceptor

How to implement a validation for each file upload API calls request on image size limit and compress its size when exceeding the defined size limit in spring boot application?

Answer (score 1):

For implementing such kind of validation I have used Spring Frameworks's interceptor.

Interceptor intercepts all API calls from client side. So by using this technique we can intercept our required request which we need to fulfill our validation.
I have created an interceptor by using Spring Framework's HandlerInterceptor interface. After it I have used MultipartFile interface for creating compressed MultipartFile to inject it into the incomming requests. And then done configuraion for our interceptor by implementing WebMvcConfigurer interface.

So here my implementation goes step by step:

1. I have created an interceptor class by extending org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor  like this:

   ```
   public class CompressionInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
       @Override
       public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
           // Logic before the request is handled
       }

       @Override
       public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
           // Logic after the request is handled but before the view is rendered
       }

       @Override
       public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
           // Logic after the entire request-response cycle is completed
       }
   }
   ```

The above is basic structure of an Spring's interceptor.

2. Now I have modified above as I have required:

   ```
   import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
   import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
   import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.util.Iterator;
   import java.util.List;
   import java.util.Objects;

   import javax.imageio.IIOImage;
   import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
   import javax.imageio.ImageWriteParam;
   import javax.imageio.ImageWriter;
   import javax.imageio.stream.ImageOutputStream;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
   import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;
   import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
   import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest;
   import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor;
   import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

   import com.i4o.dms.kubota.common.service.CustomMultipartFile;

   public class CompressionInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

       /* constant values in application.property file:
       image.maxFileSize=5000000    //5MB
       image.compressLimitSize=2000000    //2MB
       image.compressionQualityVal = 0.1f
       */

       @Value("${image.maxFileSize}")
       private long maxFileSize; 

       @Value("${image.compressLimitSize}")
       private long compressLimitSize; 

       @Value("${image.compressionQualityVal}")
       private float compressionQualityVal;


       @Override
       public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
           // Logic before the request is handled
           //Called here because we need to validate in state of pre operation
           //checking whether the request is multipart file else return true.
           if(request instanceof MultipartHttpServletRequest) {
               return validateImage(request, response);
           }
           return true;
       }

       @Override
       public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
           // Logic after the request is handled but before the view is rendered
       }

       @Override
       public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
           // Logic after the entire request-response cycle is completed
       }

       private boolean validateImage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
           MultiValueMap<String, MultipartFile> multiFileMap = ((MultipartHttpServletRequest) request).getMultiFileMap();

           for (String str : multiFileMap.keySet()) {
               List<MultipartFile> multipartList = multiFileMap.get(str);

               for (int i = 0; i < multipartList.size(); i++) { 
                   MultipartFile file = multipartList.get(i);

                   if (isImgageUnderSize(file)) {
                       // Image file size exceeds the allowed limit
                       response.sendError(403, "Image file size exceeds the allowed limit.");
                       response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);

                       return false;
                   } 
                   else if (isEligibleForCompression(file)) {
                       System.out.println("Media size before compression: " + file.getSize());

                       try {
                           //Creating cmpressed multipart file
                           MultipartFile compressedImage = createCompressedMultipartFile(file);

                           //Injecting the compressed file into request container to the same file stored on particular index
                           ((MultipartHttpServletRequest) request).getMultiFileMap().get(str).set(i, compressedImage);

                       } catch (IOException e) {
                           response.sendError(500, "There is some error while compressing the file");
                           response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
                           e.printStackTrace();
                           return false;
                       }
                   }
               } 
           }
           return true;
       }

       private MultipartFile createCompressedMultipartFile(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
           byte[] compressedByteArr = compressImage(file.getBytes());

           //Creating MutipartFile using our CustomMultipartFile class. 
           MultipartFile compressedImage = new CustomMultipartFile(file.getName(), file.getOriginalFilename(), file.getContentType(), compressedByteArr);

           return compressedImage;
       }

       private byte[] compressImage(byte[] imageData) throws IOException {
           float compressionQuality = compressionQualityVal;  //value range 0 - 1 where 0 is low quality.

           ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData);
           BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(bais);

           ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

           //filling ByteArrayOutputStream with compressed image bytes
           compressBufferedImage(originalImage, compressionQuality, baos);

           //closing ByteArrayInputStream.
           bais.close();

           return baos.toByteArray();
       }

       public void compressBufferedImage(BufferedImage image, float compressionQuality, ByteArrayOutputStream output) {
           try {

               // Get all available writers
               Iterator<ImageWriter> writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg");

               if (writers.hasNext()) {
                   ImageWriter writer = writers.next();

                   // Set compression parameters
                   ImageWriteParam writeParam = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
                   writeParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
                   writeParam.setCompressionQuality(compressionQuality);

                   ImageOutputStream imageOutput = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(output);
                   writer.setOutput(imageOutput);

                   // Write the image with compression
                   writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), writeParam);

                   // Close streams
                   imageOutput.close();

                   writer.dispose();

                   System.out.println("Image compressed successfully.");
               } else {
                   System.err.println("No suitable image writer found.");
               }
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }

       private boolean isImageFile(MultipartFile file) {
           return Objects.requireNonNull(file.getContentType()).startsWith("image");
       }

       private boolean isImgageUnderSize(MultipartFile file) {
           return file != null && isImageFile(file) && file.getSize() > maxFileSize;
       }

       private boolean isEligibleForCompression(MultipartFile file) {
           return file != null && isImageFile(file) && file.getSize() < maxFileSize && file.getSize() > compressLimitSize;
       }
   }
   ```

Intstead of using this method createCompressedMultipartFile(file) for creating multipart file we can also use this line of code:

```
InputStream compressedInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(compressImage(file.getBytes()));
MultipartFile mockMultipartFile = new MockMultipartFile(file.getName(), file.getOriginalFilename(), file.getContentType(), compressedInputStream);
```

But for above we need to add this dependency first so that we can use MockMultipartFile class:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

You can use this line of code to check wheather the file compressed correctly or not  by generating the file to a specific location:

```
Iterator<ImageWriter> writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg");

if (writers.hasNext()) {
    ImageWriter writer = writers.next();

    // Set compression parameters
    ImageWriteParam writeParam = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
    writeParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
    writeParam.setCompressionQuality(compressionQuality);
    
    FileImageOutputStream output = new FileImageOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\abc\\Downloads\\abc.jpg"));
    writer.setOutput(output);
    
    writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), writeParam);
    
    output.close();
    writer.dispose();
    
    System.out.println("Image compressed successfully.");
}
```

3. We need to create a class for generating MultipartFile file by impementing MultipartFile interface as follows:

   ```
   import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStream;

   import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

   public class CustomMultipartFile implements MultipartFile {

       private final String name;
       private final String originalFilename;
       private final String contentType;
       private final byte[] bytes;

       public CustomMultipartFile(String name, String originalFilename, String contentType, byte[] bytes) {
           this.name = name;
           this.originalFilename = originalFilename;
           this.contentType = contentType;
           this.bytes = bytes;
       }

       @Override
       public String getName() {
           return name;
       }

       @Override
       public String getOriginalFilename() {
           return originalFilename;
       }

       @Override
       public String getContentType() {
           return contentType;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean isEmpty() {
           return bytes.length == 0;
       }

       @Override
       public long getSize() {
           return bytes.length;
       }

       @Override
       public byte[] getBytes() throws IOException {
           return bytes;
       }

       @Override
       public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
           return new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
       }

       @Override
       public void transferTo(File dest) throws IOException, IllegalStateException {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       }
   }
   ```
4. After completing 3rd step we need to configure our above written interceptor as follows:

   ```
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
   import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
   import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

   import com.i4o.dms.kubota.common.interceptors.CompressionInterceptor;

   @Configuration
   public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

       @Override
       public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
           registry.addInterceptor(compressionInterceptor());
       }

       @Bean
       CompressionInterceptor compressionInterceptor() {
           return new CompressionInterceptor();
       }
   }
   ```

Now for each MultipartFile http request the image file attched get compressed automatically and APIs will get the compressed file for further use to fulfill business logics.